# объясните как работает эта рекурсия

Tags: c#, рекурсия

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
  
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(SumCyfr(477));
    }
    static long SumCyfr(long a) // рекурсивный метод
    {          
        if (a == 0)
            return 0; 
        else
            return SumCyfr(a / 10) + a % 10;
   }
}
}
```

Заранее скажу
я понимаю, что  %10 дает последнее число и /10 отсекает последнее число(в целочисленном типе), но не могу почему-то понять как это работает даже с отладкой, скорее всего упускаю что-то очевидное.

Comment: Не только отсекает, но и уменьшает число в ≈10 раз

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, вы можете поставить от него слева зеленую галочку.

Answer (score 2):

477%10 + 47%10 + 4%10 + 0(т.к. 4/10=0)= 18

при a = 0 функция заканчивается.
В другом случае оно возвращает последнюю цифру числа a  +  суммуцифр(a/10) и так по кругу, пока числа a не станет ровно нулю.

Comment: .... я как обычно. Спасибо большое! Понял свою ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Учимся понимать код при помощи дебага:

1. ставишь брейппоинт перед первым вызовом функции
2. запускаешь под дебагом (ф5, НО НЕ Ctrl+F5!!! )
3. смотришь на все значения переменных
4. нажимаешь ф11
5. Повторять пункты 3 и 4 пока не поймешь как все работает

Если все равно непонятно -- можно ввести 4 переменные посредника - каждая переменная на одно атомарное(максимально простое) действие.

```
static long SumCyfr(long a) // рекурсивный метод
{          
    if (a == 0)
        return 0; 
    else
    {
        var a1 = a / 10;
        var a2 = SumCyfr(a1);
        var a3 = a % 10
        var rez = a2 + a3;

        return rez;
    }
}
```

и повторить все действия с дебагом.

Comment: @Skait настоятельно рекомендую перечитать мой обновленный ответ и перепройти путь дебага заново. Даже если второй ответ тебе понравился больше. Ответ Битного овоща дает тебе ответ на этот вопрос, а мой ответ будет помогать до конца жизни :)